# Compile JS module with Webpack before requiring it inside a loader

Tags: webpack, webpack-loader

I'm writing a loader for Webpack and one of its options is a string containing a path to a js file. This js file is then required in my loader because I need to get some data from it. The problem is that I'd like webpack to compile this js file before I require it my loader. The reason for that is that I'm requiring an image in the js file and I'd like to use webpack's require instead of node's require so that I'll get a path to that image.

Some code might help

the loader:

```
// ...

//assume options.data is './file.js'
const data = require(options.data);

// ...
```

file.js

```
const img = require('@/assets/my-image.png');

module.exports = { image: img }
```

This doesn't work because when I do `require(options.data)` node loads `file.js` and when it tries to `require('@/assets/my-image.png')` node throws an error because, obviously, it can't find the module `@/assets/my-image.png`.

I could use `loadModule` to get the processed source code of `file.js` but I don't know how to specify a javascript loader or something like that in the request parameter of `loadModule`.

How can I get webpack to compile `file.js` before I require it in my module? Is that even possible? If not, any workarounds?

Comment: You can create a plugin that is connected to an early hook and have it compile your image, haven't tried it but it sounds due able. no?

Comment: I don't really know how I would go about that. I don't really want to handle the image (or any other file my `file.js` requires), I'd like them to be handled by webpack with the correct loaders specified in `webpack.config.js`. If I handled the files by myself I'd need to write code for each file type the user might want to load, which would make the scope of the project way larger than it should be (and make it harder to maintain).